# Xcode 7 Archive size large

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, archive, xcode7

I've previously been using Xcode 6 to write my Swift app. I've now upgraded to Xcode 7 and upgraded my Swift syntax.

Previously, when I did an archive of my app, I'm sure it was only around 12MB in size when viewed in finder. Now, it is much larger (112MB).

I have now disabled bundles in my build settings as some other posts have suggested, and this has brought the archive down to 74.9MB.

Trouble is that uploading these large file sizes become very heavy on my internet connection and take ages to get processed by Apple iTunes connect.

Is there any way of reducing the size of the archive since I'm using Xcode 7?

[image: Screenshot of project files]

[image: Screenshot of archive file]

Comment: With all respect, the problem here is not the images in the app. Here's a screenshot of the project folder: http://i.imgur.com/QypSe2R.png and here is a screenshot of the archive that was created from the project: http://i.imgur.com/qOvvLN7.png

Comment: No no, all my fault. See now my answer below and sorry for the noise earlier.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The problem is that you turned on BitCode:

[image]

Bitcode is *big*. But that's what it takes if you want the [advantages that it offers](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AppThinning/AppThinning.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH35-SW2).

So the irony is that with bitcode, your app can be much *smaller* when downloaded directly to a user's device (because it can be thinned, optimized for that device), but it has to be much *bigger* when uploaded to the App Store.

Comment: Okay thanks. I guess I'll be keeping this BitCode turned on for its advantages, and have to put up with the long upload times. Thanks for your post and I'm glad we sorted things back there! :)

Comment: Just be glad you don't live at my house. Upload takes a _really_ long time here! :(

Comment: I mean the size of the compressed XCode project is 5.5 MB. The archive is 250 MB. I also live with a terrible internet connection 1 mbps.

Comment: @myatmins Yes, Apple just assumes everyone has huge screens, fast computers, and incredible internet.

Comment: @silexcorp Why don't you look at the archive and _see_ why it is 600MB? As for the other part of your comment, please don't use Stack Overflow comments to complain about irrelevant matters.